# VB.NET ~ how does one navigate to a website and download the html then parse out code to only display input elements?

Tags: html, vb.net, parsing

I have tried a few things like converting HTML to XML and then using an XML navigator to get input elements but I get lost whenever I start this process.

What I am trying to do is to navigate to a website which will be loaded using textbox1.text

Then download the html and parse out the input elements like . username, password, etc and place the element by type (id or name) into the richtextbox with the attribute beside the name.

Example.

```
Username id="username"
Password id="password"
```

Any clues or how to properly execute an HTML to XML conveter, reader, parser?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need a good HTML parsing library (instead of trying to use an XML parser).  The [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) often fits this need.  There are [other options](https://www.google.com/search?q=.net%20html%20parser) as well.

Comment: Yeah I've heard of the HTML Agility Pack but the documentation is very limited on how to use that library.

Comment: If your only after a limited number of attributes from a page, then the HTML agility pack could be overkill in this case, I achieved something similar using regex to extract the information  after I had used a Streamreader to read the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like below uses a streamreader to extract the source of the page into a string `result`

```
  Dim uri As String = "https://www.yourUrl.com"          

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(uri), HttpWebRequest)
    Dim objRequest As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri)
    Dim result As String
    objRequest.Method = "GET"
    Dim objResponse As HttpWebResponse = objRequest.GetResponse()
    Dim sr As StreamReader
    sr = New StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream())

    result = sr.ReadToEnd()
    sr.Close
```

Then use regular expression (regex) to extra the attributes needed. for example something like this

```
Dim pattern As String = "(?<=Username id="")\w+"

    Dim m0 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(result, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline)
    Dim m As Match
    Dim k As Integer = 0
    dim strUserID as String = ""

    For Each m In m0

    'extract the values for username id
    strUserID = m0[k].Value;

    k=k+1
    Next
```

You'll need to change the `pattern` so it can pick up the other attributes you want to find, but this shouldn't be difficult